# Create Mobile shortcut to website

Tags: php, android, jquery, ios, blackberry

I would like to create an icon for my website when user visits my website from mobile. I assume i will have to check the OS which request the url and on knowing from where the request came ie Apple, Android or Blackberry phones and executing script which will create icon if accepted by user..

Can this be done ? If yes, then how ?

Comment: You can get that information from the header

Comment: What do you mean by "an icon for my website" ?

Comment: Can you explain more that what you are trying yo do

Comment: take look : http://www.olivieralbertini.com/tutorial/create-icon-for-mobile you should find some interessing stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the code below this will work

```
<?php
$ismobile = 0;
$container = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

// Mobile Company And Os
$useragents = array ('Blazer','Palm','Handspring','Nokia','Kyocera','Samsung','Motorola','Smartphone','Windows CE','Blackberry','WAP','SonyEricsson','PlayStation Portable','LG','MMP','OPWV','Symbian','EPOC','android','Android');

foreach ( $useragents as $useragents )
{
    if(strstr($container,$useragents))
    {
        $ismobile = 1;
        $browser = $useragents;
    }
}
if ( $ismobile == 1 ) 
{
    echo "<p>Browsing Using ".$browser." device</p>";
}
?>
```

And The Out Put Will Be Like Below

> Browsing Using Android device